# View overlapping another view

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, interface-builder

I am struggling with Interface Builder to make one view overlay another view and I still cannot figure out how to do it.

What I need to do is that the view with yellow circle (profile picture) partially overlays the blue view as shown on the picture bellow.

[image]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Simple use of constraints should do the trick for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the screenshot that gives an idea of the constraints you can add to orange view to get the desired results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Storyboard set `circle`s top constraint to a negative value (-30) and un-tick the `clip to bounds` checkbox on its `superview`.